# Firebase work-around for missing tenantId in user().onCreate() response?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use multi-tenancy in firebase.  All has gone well, except that after creating a user, the returned user missing the tenantId.  I'm trying to create a custom claim with hasura so that I can tell the user's tenant:

```
exports.processSignUp = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  const customClaims = {
    "https://hasura.io/jwt/claims": {
      "x-hasura-default-role": "user",
      "x-hasura-allowed-roles": ["user"],
      "x-hasura-user-id": user.uid,
      "x-hasura-tenant-id": user.tenantId,
    },
  };
```

However, there seems to be a bug where the `onCreate` request does not properly return the tenantId, as acknowledged here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160809045

Unfortunately I can't fetch the user again to try and grab the tenantId there because the user is scoped to the tenant.  It won't find the user given the user's id because I haven't set the tenant.

Does anyone more familiar with firebase/google identity management know of a work-around until that bug is fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I already meet familiar with this case. Using Google identity tenant and Hasura too

And I can check user.tenantId as normally. I see this post 1 year ago. But still want to give you comment with a familiar case

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).